# how to do i want to get this string from log.txt file

Tags: python, c, awk, sed

log.txt format:

```
;Index,Level,StripSize,SizeinMB,Status,Bootable,Array,Name
0,0,32kB,8192,"Normal","Yes",0,"FFS"
1,0,128kB,19046,"Normall","No",0,"Dev_Cache"
2,0,64kB,305244,"Normalll","Yes",1,"0W24SWKT"
```

or other format:

```
;Index,Level,StripSize,SizeinMB,Status,Bootable,Array,Name
0,0,32kB,8192,"Normal","Yes",0,"FFS"
1,0,128kB,19046,"Available","No",0,"Dev_Cache"
2,0,64kB,305244,"Normal","Yes",1,"0W24SWKT"
```

below is my step:

```
iffs.sed
/Bootable/{
n;
s/^.*[0-9],\"([a-zA-Z]+)\",.*$/set abc=\1/p;
}
1. sed -nrf iffs.sed log.txt
result: set abc=Normal
2. sed "2d" log.txt |sed -nrf iffs.sed
result: set abc=Normal or Available
3. sed "2,3d" log.txt |sed -nrf iffs.sed
result: set abc=Normal
```

could you help to simple way? windows os and winpe 3.0 environment.
and i want to get this result"set abc2= Normal; set abc3=Normal or Available;set abc4=Normal "

Comment: What string are you trying to get?

Comment: This question is tagged as Python, C, sed, and AWK?!

Comment: Its a good thing the data format shouts "use awk" or I would be asking the same question.  Right now I can get  only awk -F, '...{print "abc=" $5};...' log.txt

Comment: i want get "Normal" or "Available" in below three line.
tagged as awk too

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
for line in open('log.txt'):
    print 'abc=' + line.split(',')[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat data 
;Index,Level,StripSize,SizeinMB,Status,Bootable,Array,Name
0,0,32kB,8192,"Normal","Yes",0,"FFS"
1,0,128kB,19046,"Available","No",0,"Dev_Cache"
2,0,64kB,305244,"Normal","Yes",1,"0W24SWKT"
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat doit.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=",";
  ind=ARGV[1];
  ARGV[1]="";
}

$1 == ind {
  gsub(/"/, "", $5);
  print $5;
}

[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ ./doit.awk 2 data
Normal
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ ./doit.awk 1 data
Available
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$
```

And if your indexes are guaranteed not to repeat in a file, you can put a `nextfile` after `print $5` to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1d;=;s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/' log.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/=/;s/^/set abc/'
set abc2=Normal
set abc3=Available
set abc4=Normal
```